# Is the space of holomorphic maps a manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, cv.complex-variables

To be more specific:
Let $Q\subset\mathbb{C}$ be a Lipschitz bounded domain, and $V$ is a compact complex manifold without boundary. Consider the set of holomorphic maps $f:Q\rightarrow V$, and $f\in H^s(Q,V)$, with $s$ sufficiently large(say $s>3$). The notation $H^s(Q,V)$ means the derivatives up to order $s$ are in $L^2$(under local coordinates of $V$) Now the question is whether this set forms a complex Hilbert manifold? How do we define the coordinate chart?

Actually all I need is to identify the neighborhood of some give holomorphic map $f_0$ with an open subset of a Hilbert space(without asking for smoothness of coordinate transformation)

Comment: The real analogue of the question is easy, and coordinate chart can be constructed via the exponential map.

Comment: You will probably define charts (if you can) in terms of tubular neighborhoods of $f \partial Q$ and a finite chart on $V$, the harmonic maximum principle et.c.  You will probably use that $\partial Q$ is both compact and piecewise rectifiable (and it is only on neighborhoods of $\partial Q$ that $s$ is really important).  I sincerely hope the $Q$ you have in mind has $\partial Q$ of finitely many components?

Comment: Just think of $Q$ to be simple, say $Q$ is a square or polygon. I don`t see how to use the tubular neighborhoods of $f\partial Q$. It does not necessarily behaves nicely under the image so I am not sure if tubular neighborhoods exists. Also does the use of tubular neighborhood compatible with being holomorphic?

Comment: so... have you answered your question yet?

Comment: anyways, of course tubular neighborhoods do not behave well w.r.t. holomorphic maps! that's not the point. The point is to use holomorphic rigidity to reduce the size of your question from something 2-d to something ... somewhat less.  E.g., I'm sure you can work out that a map $Q\to V$ is determined by its germ at any point, which can be specified by a power series w.r.t. some chart in $V$, but also that not all power series will work (and there are more details); but relating series to $H^s$ may be hard, so consider perhaps extension problems for boundary perturbations instead.

Comment: I am not sure how it helps. Maybe you can be more specific.

Comment: You want charts, which means you want to parametrize [contractible] neighborhoods of points.  A point, for you, is a holomorphic map $Q \to V$. You've said your prefered $Q$ are contractible, so an exercise: a small holomorphic perturbation is determined by its restriction to $\partial Q$.  When you've tried that, we'll try to see what else you need.